# How can I make a gnome panel only appear if I have a second monitor hooked up?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, gnome-panel

I have a laptop with Ubuntu installed on it and I'm constantly switching from just my laptop to also having a monitor.  When I'm using the laptop screen and monitor, I have a panel on each monitor that shows the windows open for that monitor.  If I switch to just using the laptop screen, then both panels end up on the same screen.  How can I configure one of the panels to only show up if I have two monitors?  Or can I at least "suspend" one of the panels somehow so I don't have to set it up the way I like it every time I switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the *screen* option for this panel via **gconf-editor**.

Run gconf-editor and navigate to the panel options at `/apps/panel/toplevels/panel_1/` (your panel name may vary slightly). You should see an option *screen* as shown below. Try configuring this to your liking.

I'm not sure this will work, as I have a feeling that when you switch to using just the laptop screen, this value is automatically changed to the available screen. It's worth a shot.

If you use [Xinerama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama), there's also an option to configure the monitor the panel appears on.

If none of these work, I'd suggest you enable `auto-hide`, and set a very low `auto_hide_size` so the panel is barely visible when you switch to one screen.

I haven't researched this yet, but if there is a command-line way to modify these values, I'd just use a script to tweak these values so the panel is hidden when I want it.

[image: gconf-editor]

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did (on Ubuntu 10.04):

To fully hide the panel, you can set monitor to `-1` using `gconftool-2`. The only caveat is sometimes you have to kill/restart gnome-panel after changing the monitor setting. This should do the job (killall without rerunning gnome-panel doesn't always bring it back):

```
gnome-panel --replace
```

There is a blog post here with a simple script that you can hook onto nvidia-settings or gnome-display-properties:

> http://blog.zoomeren.nl/2010/03/05/a-gnome-panel-for-each-connected-monitor/

Since I use Nvidia, I did `nvidia-settings -tq TwinView` to check if TwinView is on, but you might not be able to tell the difference between two and three monitors.

Answer (score 0):

GConf includes a command line tool, gconftool-2. You can use the gconftool–2 command to perform the following tasks:

- Set the values of keys.
- Display the values of keys.
- Install schemas from schema definition files when you install an application.

For example, use the following command to display the values of all keys in the /desktop/gnome directory and subdirectories.

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-list /desktop/gnome
```